# declare type of return value from class method to be a object of said class python

Tags: python

I have a class File and a class Directory, a child of File. The Directory class has an attribute, contents, which is a list of File objects. In a method, I want to return only subdirectories - only the Directory objects in the list.

```py
class File:
    # irrelevant stuff
    pass

class Directory(File):
    contents: list[File] = []
    
    def __init__(self, contents):
        self.contents = contents
    
    def get_subdirectories():
        subdirectories = []
        for file in self.contents:
            if isinstance(file, Directory):
                subdirectories.append(file)
        return subdirectories
```

This code works perfectly fine, but as soon as I want to declare the type of the return value `def get_subdirectories() -> list[Directory]:` I get `NameError: name 'Directory' is not defined`.

I know type declaration in python is not necessary, but I still like to do it.

I also tried `list[self]`, which doesn't make any sense and unsurprisingly gives a similar error.

I thought of creating a dummy Directory class and a structure like this:

```py
class File:
    pass

class DummyDirectory(File):
    pass

class Directory(DummyDirectory):
    # same stuff as previously
    def get_subdirectories() -> list[DummyDirectory]:
        pass
```

But that adds an unnecessary layer of complexity and looks awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `annotations` from `__future__` module.

```py
from __future__ import annotations 

class File:
    # irrelevant stuff
    pass


class Directory(File):
    contents: list[File] = []

    def __init__(self, contents):
        self.contents = contents

    def get_subdirectories(self) -> List[Directory]:
        subdirectories = []
        for file in self.contents:
            if isinstance(file, Directory):
                subdirectories.append(file)
        return subdirectories
```